# MPI_Gather send and recieving array error

Tags: c, mpi

```
    #include<mpi.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(int argc,char * argv[])
    {
      int rank,size,m;
      int arr[1000];
      int b[100];
      MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
      MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
      MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

      if(rank == 0)
      {
        scanf("%d",&m);
        for(int i=0;i<size*m;i++)
        {
          scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }

      }
      MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Scatter(arr,m,MPI_INT,b,m,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

      printf("in process %d \n",rank);
      for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
      {
        printf("%d ",b[i]);
      }
      printf("\n");

      MPI_Finalize();
      return 0;
    }
```

Input

```
mpiexec -n 4 ./three
```

Actual Output

```
in process 2 
in process 1 
in process 3 
2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
in process 0 
1 2
```

Expected Output

```
2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
in process 0
1 2
in process 1
3 4 
in process 2
5 6 
in process 3
7 8
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not have my magic crystal ball with me to guess all the missing code or _three_ contents etc. `if(rank == 0)` while _rank_ is not initialized ?

Comment: @bruno rank is initialized `MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);`

Comment: ah ok, I didn't see, I remove my remark about that then. But that change nothing for the rest ;-) (and I formatted your question to be more readable)

Comment: Please edit your question with a [MCVE]. You can at least hardcode `m` and `arr` on rank `0` and share your debugging efforts. Keep in mind the outputs of all the ranks are interleaved so there is not a unique output to expect. If you use Open MPI, you can `mpirun --tag-output ...` to have every line automatically prefixed with the process rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not broadcast the value of m so only rank 0 has a correct value - it looks like it is defaulting to m=0 on other ranks, hence their lack of output.

The barrier is not required - MPI collectives do all the necessary synchronisation automatically.

If you replace your barrier call with:

```
MPI_Bcast(&m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

then your code works as expected (subject to the output not being as clean as you might expect as pointed out by Gilles above).